# How to get all keys and values in list of Nested dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x

```
di = [{ "k": [1, 3, 5], "k1":  { "k10" : 4, "k11": [4, 7, 9], "k12" : { "k120" : { "k121" : "v121" }}, "k14" : 6}},  {"k22":  { "k221" : "v122"}}]
    
key_list = list()
val_list = list()
    
for i in di:
   key_list.extend(i.keys())
   val_list.extend(i.values())
    
for i in val_list:
   if "dict" in str(type(i)):
      key_list.extend(i.keys())
      val_list.remove(i)
      val_list.extend(i.values())
            
for i in val_list:
   if "dict" in str(type(i)):
      key_list.extend(i.keys())
      val_list.remove(i)
      val_list.extend(i.values())
    
print("Key list: ",key_list)
print("Vlaue list: ", val_list)
```

"""This is giving my answer but i need a optimised way and also for N nested dictionary how to get all keys and values, I need get all keys in a list and all values in a list."""

Answer (score 0):

About optimization: If there is a reason of existing hierarchy there is not "optimised way" to disrespect the hierarchy, otherwise a real optimization needs to include a change not to construct the hierarchy that would be disrespected later.

I wrote the following, is not optimized but decently efficient and concise, it does something in the direction of what you imprecisely asked: (I let you refine what you intend to be returned, I noticed that you silently excluded to return those **value** whose type is **dict**ionary, I didn't make such discrimination). To help to understand the flexibility of the code I made some examples as cases controlled by the behavioral variable `bkv`, this behavioral variable can be squeezed when you know what you want to obtain.

```
dictype=type({})
listype=type([])
def through(ref,bkv):
    """ bkv in binary 01=1 yield  key
                      10=2 yield      value
                      11=3 yield (key,value) """
    if type(ref)==listype:
        for x in ref:
            yield from through(x,bkv)
    elif type(ref)==dictype:
        for kv in ref.items():
            if bkv==1:
                 yield kv[0]
            elif bkv==2:
                 yield kv[1]
            elif bkv==3:
                 yield kv
            else:
                 throw(TypeError, "Not implemented")
            yield from through(kv[1],bkv)
di = [
    { "k": [1, 3, 5],
      "k1":  { "k10" : 4,
               "k11": [4, 7, 9],
               "k12" : { "k120" : { "k121" : "v121" }},
               "k14" : 6}},
    {"k22":  { "k221" : "v122"}}
]
list_keys=[x for x in through(di,1)]
list_values=[x for x in through(di,2)]
list_keyval=[x for x in through(di,3)]

print("Key list: ",list_keys)
print("Values list (all, not excluding dict values): ",list_values)
print("all (Key,Value) pairs:", list_keyval)
```

Comment: I need it for Nth level nested but its the same 3 level nested.

Comment: To limit the deepness level add a parameter `, N` to the recursive `through` generator that I wrote. add a condition inside `through` to only perform `if N>0:` ,  then you pass as `, N-1` on each recursive call